# Drupal Views Relationships and Arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a Person content type. It has a node reference field of a company which is also a content type. I then have a content type called Project. A project has a node reference to a company content type. I want to list all the projects related to a person id (nid)

If I abstract this away from views and Drupal and each content type had it's own table I would use something like.

```
Select ProjectName from Projects where CompanyID IN (select CompanyID from Perons where PersonID = 10)
```

Can I do something similar in Views?

My PersonID would be an argument.
This would bring back the person content type. I would then use a relationship to bring back the company.

I now don't know know how to link the company up to the project...

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the answer you are looking for, but I typically will do one of two things for the double relationship thing.

1. Skip views altogether and do a custom query.
2. Create a view for the first relationship.  Inside the view templates for this, I will

2a.  Just do a node_load() to pull in the nodes for second relationship.

2b.  Manually instantiate another view (either via views_embed_view() or views_get_view_result()) passing in the proper argument.

Comment: Follow up questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727201/drupal-performing-a-query-against-the-database this is when trying to do option 1.